# Issue on configure hive on spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, bigdata

I have downloaded spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7. Could any one advise how to configure hive on this and use in scala console? Now I am able to run RDD's on file using Scala (spark-shell console).

Comment: could you please elaborate more on what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @MR Srinivas: so now i can use spark-shell console for scala coding in spark. i have done some map reduce functions on files. then i came to know hive for storing and retrieving data and its a query like structure. i would like to try with it. i am trying to configure hive. its showing URI exceptions like ware-house folder missing and few others, error occurred when i try to create a table using hive query. i din set any EV for hive, i just do two import package for hive context, if am wrong in configure pleass share me any links for step by step process of installation

Comment: check these links [hive installation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm), [Hive on Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started).

Comment: @MR Srinivas: i was following the second link from the beginning, can u please let me know that wtr i need to download hive externally from apache hive site? or just set 'set hive.execution.engine=spark;'

Comment: if `HIVE` is working fine with default execution engine then follow 2nd link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the official Hive on Spark documentation:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

You can set on Hive the spark engine by using the following command:

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
```

or by adding it on hive-site.xml (refer to kanishka post)

Then prior to Hive 2.2.0, copy the spark-assembly jar to HIVE_HOME/lib.

Since Hive 2.2.0, Hive on Spark runs with Spark 2.0.0 and above, which doesn't have an assembly jar.

To run with YARN mode (either yarn-client or yarn-cluster), copy the following jars to HIVE_HOME/lib.

> scala-library
>
> spark-core
>
> spark-network-common

Set the spark_home:

```
export $SPARK_HOME=/path-to-spark
```

Start Spark Master and Workers:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master

spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://MASTER_IP:PORT
```

Configure Spark:

```
set spark.master=<Spark Master URL>;
set spark.executor.memory=512m; 
set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=10~20% of spark.executor.memory(value);     
set spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your hive-site.xml on spark conf directory

Comment: i just want to know wtr i need to download hive from apache hive?? hive-site.xml file will be available where??? please clarify thanks??

Answer (score 0):

Hive can support multiple execution engine. Like TEZ, Spark.
You can set the property in hive-site.xml

```
</property> 
<name>hive.execution.engine</name>
<value>spark</value>
<description>
 I am choosing Spark as the execution engine
</description>
</property>
```

Copy jars spark-assembly jar to HIVE_HOME/lib

Set the spark_home

set the below properties

```
set spark.master=<Spark Master URL>
set spark.eventLog.enabled=true;
set spark.eventLog.dir=<Spark event log folder (must exist)>
set spark.executor.memory=512m;             
set spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer;
```

Above steps would suffice i think

Comment: I have copied all the jars from spark to hive, coz xatly i don knw wat u mean by spark-assembly jar .